# CIDetector and UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, orientation, face-detection, core-image, cifacefeature

I'm trying to implement the built-in iOS 5 face detection API. I'm using an instance of `UIImagePickerController` to allow the user to take a photo and then I'm trying to use `CIDetector` to detect facial features. Unfortunately, `featuresInImage` always returns an array of size 0.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage* picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSNumber *orientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:
                         [picture imageOrientation]];
NSDictionary *imageOptions =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:orientation
                            forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];

CIImage *ciimage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[picture CGImage]
                                     options:imageOptions];


NSDictionary *detectorOptions =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyLow
                            forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy];
CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil
                                          options:detectorOptions];

NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:ciimage];
NSLog(@"Feature size: %d", features.count);
}
```

This always returns 0 features. However, if I use a UIImage from a file built-in to the application, the face detection works great.

I'm using code from this [Pragmatic Bookshelf article](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-11/inside-ios-).

For what it's worth, I think the error is when I convert the UIImage from the camera to a CIImage, but it could be anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@tonyc Your solution only works for a specific case that is "UIImageOrientationRight". The problem comes from the difference between the orientation in UIImage and CIDetectorImageOrientation. From iOS docs:

> CIDetectorImageOrientation
>
> A key used to specify the display orientation of the image whose features you want to detect. This key
> is an NSNumber object with the same value as defined by the TIFF and
> EXIF specifications; values can range from 1 through 8. The value
> specifies where the origin (0,0) of the image is located. If not
> present, the default value is 1, which means the origin of the image
> is top, left. For details on the image origin specified by each value,
> see kCGImagePropertyOrientation.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> Declared in CIDetector.h.

So the problem now is the conversion between these two orientations, here is what I did in my code, I tested and it worked for all orientations:

```
int exifOrientation;
switch (self.image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        exifOrientation = 1;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        exifOrientation = 3;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        exifOrientation = 8;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        exifOrientation = 6;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 2;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 4;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 5;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 7;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh }; // TODO: read doc for more tuneups
CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];

NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.image.CGImage]
                                          options:@{CIDetectorImageOrientation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:exifOrientation]}];
```

Comment: what is self.image.imageOrientation can you please explain?

Comment: Please advise here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399074/cidetector-not-detecting-proper-rectangle-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

Sure enough, after spending a day looking into this and being stumped, I've found a solution an hour after posting this.

I eventually noticed that the face detection did work in landscape, but not in portrait.

Turns out I needed these options:

```
NSDictionary *imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6]
                                                         forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:ciimage options:imageOptions];
```

Comment: **Swift4.2**  var imageOptions = [CIDetectorImageOrientation : NSNumber(value: 6)]
            var features = faceDetector!.features(in: myImage, options: imageOptions as? [String : Any])

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Version**

```
var exifOrientation : Int
switch (inputImage.imageOrientation)
{
case UIImageOrientation.up:
    exifOrientation = 1;
case UIImageOrientation.down:
    exifOrientation = 3;
case UIImageOrientation.left:
    exifOrientation = 8;
case UIImageOrientation.right:
    exifOrientation = 6;
case UIImageOrientation.upMirrored:
    exifOrientation = 2;
case UIImageOrientation.downMirrored:
    exifOrientation = 4;
case UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored:
    exifOrientation = 5;
case UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
    exifOrientation = 7;
}

let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: inputImage.cgImage!)
let options = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: options)!
let faces = faceDetector.features(in: ciImage, options:["CIDetectorImageOrientation":exifOrientation])
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem - the face detector was working in orientations that didn't match the image orientation property.
[iOS face detector orientation and setting of CIImage orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935626/ios-face-detector-orientation-and-setting-of-ciimage-orientation)

a quick work around that I found to help with that is to disregard the image orientation all together and "flatten" the image (so that there is no image orientation data)

I used this code:

http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/

and sure enough looks like it is working much better for front camera pics. I haven't tried enough on landscape to tell if it has helped there but looks promising

Comment: Your link is broken