# iOS face detector orientation and setting of CIImage orientation

Tags: ios, face-detection, core-image, ciimage, cifacefeature

***EDIT*** found this code that helped with front camera images http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/

Hope others have had a similar issue and can help me out. Haven't found a solution yet. (It may seem a bit long but just a bunch of helper code)

I'm using the ios face detector on images aquired from the camera (front and back) as well as images from the gallery (I'm using the `UIImagePicker` - for both image capture by camera and image selection from the gallery - not using  avfoundation for taking pictures like in the squarecam demo)

I am getting really messed up coordinates for the detection (if any) so I wrote a short debug method to get the bounds of the faces as well as a utility that draws a square over them, and i wanted to check for which orientation the detector was working:

```
#define RECTBOX(R)   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:R]
- (NSArray *)detectFaces:(UIImage *)inputimage
{
    _detector = \[CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:\[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyLow forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy\]\];
    NSNumber *orientation = \[NSNumber numberWithInt:\[inputimage imageOrientation\]\]; // i also saw code where they add +1 to the orientation
    NSDictionary *imageOptions = \[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:orientation forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation\];

    CIImage* ciimage = \[CIImage imageWithCGImage:inputimage.CGImage options:imageOptions\];


    // try like this first
    //    NSArray* features = \[self.detector featuresInImage:ciimage options:imageOptions\];
    // if not working go on to this (trying all orientations)
    NSArray* features;

    int exif;
    // ios face detector. trying all of the orientations
    for (exif = 1; exif <= 8 ; exif++)
    {
        NSNumber *orientation = \[NSNumber numberWithInt:exif\];

        NSDictionary *imageOptions = \[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:orientation forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation\];

        NSTimeInterval start = \[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate\];

        features = \[self.detector featuresInImage:ciimage options:imageOptions\];

        if (features.count > 0)
        {
            NSString *str = \[NSString stringWithFormat:@"found faces using exif %d",exif\];
                    \[faceDetection log:str\];
            break;
        }
        NSTimeInterval duration = \[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate\] - start;
        NSLog(@"faceDetection: facedetection total runtime is %f s",duration);
    }
    if (features.count > 0)
    {
        [faceDetection log:@"-I- Found faces with ios face detector"];
        for(CIFaceFeature *feature in features)
        {
            CGRect rect = feature.bounds;
            CGRect r = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,inputimage.size.height - rect.origin.y - rect.size.height,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
            [returnArray addObject:RECTBOX(r)];
        }
        return returnArray;
    } else {
        // no faces from iOS face detector. try OpenCV detector
    }
```

[1]

After trying tons of different pictures, I noticed that the face detector orientation is not consistent with the camera image property. I took a bunch of photos from the front facing camera
where the uiimage orientation was 3 (querying imageOrienation) but the face detector wasn't finding faces for that setting. When running through all of the exif possibilities, the face detector was finally picking up faces but for a different orientation all together.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7bkZ.jpg

How can I solve this? Is there a mistake in my code?

Another problem I was having, (but closely connected with the face detector), when the face detector picks up faces, but for the "wrong" orientation (happens mostly on front facing camera) the `UIImage` initially used displays correctly in a uiiimageview, but when I draw a square overlay (I am using opencv in my app so I decided to convert the `UIImage` to cvmat to draw the overlay with opencv) the whole image is rotated 90 degrees (Only the cvmat image and not the `UIImage` i initially displayed)

The reasoning I can think of here is that the face detector is messing with some buffer (context?) that the UIimage conversion to opencv mat is using. How can I seperate these buffers?

The code for converting uiimage to cvmat is (from the "famous" `UIImage` category someone made):

```
-(cv::Mat)CVMat
{

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = self.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = self.size.height;

    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data, // Pointer to backing data
                                                    cols, // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows, // Height of bitmap
                                                    8, // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0], // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace, // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), self.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    return cvMat;
}

- (id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1)
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    }
    else
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                     // Width
                                            cvMat.rows,                                     // Height
                                            8,                                              // Bits per component
                                            8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                           // Bits per pixel
                                            cvMat.step[0],                                  // Bytes per row
                                            colorSpace,                                     // Colorspace
                                            kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,  // Bitmap info flags
                                            provider,                                       // CGDataProviderRef
                                            NULL,                                           // Decode
                                            false,                                          // Should interpolate
                                            kCGRenderingIntentDefault);                     // Intent   

     self = [self initWithCGImage:imageRef];
     CGImageRelease(imageRef);
     CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
     CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

     return self;
 }  

 -(cv::Mat)CVRgbMat
 {
     cv::Mat tmpimage = self.CVMat;
     cv::Mat image;
     cvtColor(tmpimage, image, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
     return image;
 }

 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    self.prevImage = img;
 //   self.previewView.image = img;
    NSArray *arr = [[faceDetection sharedFaceDetector] detectFaces:img];
    for (id r in arr)
    {
         CGRect rect = RECTUNBOX(r);
         //self.previewView.image = img;
         self.previewView.image = [utils drawSquareOnImage:img square:rect];
    }
    [self.imgPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return;
}
```

Comment: use [this code](http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/) before running the face detector and you will never have orientation issues

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a good idea to rotate whole bunch of image pixels and match the CIFaceFeature. You can imagine redrawing at the rotated orientation is very heavy. I had the same problem, and I solved it by converting the coordinate system of the CIFaceFeature with respect to the UIImageOrientation. I extended the CIFaceFeature class with some conversion methods to get the correct point locations and bounds with respect to the UIImage and its UIImageView (or the CALayer of a UIView). The complete implementation is posted here: https://gist.github.com/laoyang/5747004. You can use directly.

Here is the most basic conversion for a point from CIFaceFeature, the returned CGPoint is converted based on image's orientation:

```
- (CGPoint) pointForImage:(UIImage*) image fromPoint:(CGPoint) originalPoint {

    CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;

    CGPoint convertedPoint;

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            convertedPoint.x = originalPoint.x;
            convertedPoint.y = imageHeight - originalPoint.y;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            convertedPoint.x = imageWidth - originalPoint.x;
            convertedPoint.y = originalPoint.y;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            convertedPoint.x = imageWidth - originalPoint.y;
            convertedPoint.y = imageHeight - originalPoint.x;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            convertedPoint.x = originalPoint.y;
            convertedPoint.y = originalPoint.x;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            convertedPoint.x = imageWidth - originalPoint.x;
            convertedPoint.y = imageHeight - originalPoint.y;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            convertedPoint.x = originalPoint.x;
            convertedPoint.y = originalPoint.y;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            convertedPoint.x = imageWidth - originalPoint.y;
            convertedPoint.y = originalPoint.x;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            convertedPoint.x = originalPoint.y;
            convertedPoint.y = imageHeight - originalPoint.x;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return convertedPoint;
}
```

And here are the category methods based on the above conversion:

```
// Get converted features with respect to the imageOrientation property
- (CGPoint) leftEyePositionForImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (CGPoint) rightEyePositionForImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (CGPoint) mouthPositionForImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (CGRect) boundsForImage:(UIImage *)image;

// Get normalized features (0-1) with respect to the imageOrientation property
- (CGPoint) normalizedLeftEyePositionForImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (CGPoint) normalizedRightEyePositionForImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (CGPoint) normalizedMouthPositionForImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (CGRect) normalizedBoundsForImage:(UIImage *)image;

// Get feature location inside of a given UIView size with respect to the imageOrientation property
- (CGPoint) leftEyePositionForImage:(UIImage *)image inView:(CGSize)viewSize;
- (CGPoint) rightEyePositionForImage:(UIImage *)image inView:(CGSize)viewSize;
- (CGPoint) mouthPositionForImage:(UIImage *)image inView:(CGSize)viewSize;
- (CGRect) boundsForImage:(UIImage *)image inView:(CGSize)viewSize;
```

(Another thing need to notice is specifying the correct EXIF orientation when extracting the face features from UIImage orientation. Quite confusing... here is what I did:

```
int exifOrientation;
switch (self.image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        exifOrientation = 1;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        exifOrientation = 3;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        exifOrientation = 8;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        exifOrientation = 6;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 2;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 4;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 5;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 7;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };
CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];

NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.image.CGImage]
                                          options:@{CIDetectorImageOrientation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:exifOrientation]}];
```

)

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 10 and Swift 3**

You can check apple example you can **detect face** or value of **barcode** and **Qrcode**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamBarcode/Introduction/Intro.html