# CIDetector Not Detecting Faces with UIImagePickerController (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, cidetector

I am trying to take a picture with the camera and then detect the faces in it. But it doesn't work... The `results` array returns a count of zero. I have tested this code with a picture of somebody from the internet and it returned 1 found face. Here is my code:

```
// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        Idea.CurrentIdea.idea.mockups.append(PFFile(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.5)!))

        //Face Detection
        let cid:CIDetector = CIDetector(ofType:CIDetectorTypeFace, context:nil, options:[CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]);

        let cii = CIImage(CGImage: pickedImage.CGImage!)

        let results:NSArray = cid.featuresInImage(cii)

        print(results.count)
        for r in results {
            let face:CIFaceFeature = r as! CIFaceFeature;
            NSLog("Face found at (%f,%f) of dimensions %fx%f", face.bounds.origin.x, face.bounds.origin.y, face.bounds.width, face.bounds.height);
        }


    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks! There isn't much on the web about it recently.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No. This was quite a while ago, I believe I bailed on the project. Try the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your image orientation and the expected image orientation for the detector are the same. See this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019107/919790